# datepicker and angular js not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, datepicker

i am trying to pass my selected date value from date picker to php file. but when i do submit the form all the value passed correctly except datepicker value, and its says undefined.

my code following

```
<form>
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
            From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
            To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />
    </div>
    <input id="txtDate" type="text" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                  $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected);
                }
            });
            $("#txtFromDate").on("change", function () {
        alert('aa');
        });
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                onSelect: function(selected) {
                   $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected);
                }
            });  
        });
    </script>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-group-btn form-group col-md-2">
        <button ng-click="searchWr(searchName,wrSearch_WrId,userDoneBy,userDateSearchType,startDateSearch,EndDateSearch,SearchByWRStatus,userHopDone)" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><b>SEARCH</b>  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

my angular js code:

```
var app=angular.module('myRequestsDisplay',['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
    app.controller('requestContl',function($scope,$http){
        $scope.searchWr = function() {
            alert($scope.startDateSearch);
            $http.post('search_data.php',{
                    'searchTitle':$scope.searchTitle,
                    'WrId':$scope.wrSearch_WrId,
                    'userDoneBy':$scope.userDoneBy,
                    'userDateSearchType':$scope.userDateSearchType,
                    'startDateSearch':$scope.startDateSearch,
                    'EndDateSearch':$scope.EndDateSearch,
                    'SearchByWRStatus':$scope.SearchByWRStatus,
                    'userHopDone':$scope.userHopDone
                }
                )
        .success(function(myData) {
                $scope.myRequestAlldata = myData;
              });
    };
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use the same date picker in Angular version... This might be easy .

Comment: which angular js? link please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uberspeck/4ht8y4nw/

Comment: Use Angular UI Datepicker (ui.bootstrap.datepicker) instead of jquery datepicker because it is easy to use with angular rather than jquery datepicker. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: either use Angular UI datepicker (as mentioned above), find another angular datepicker plugin, or create your own directive (you can use jquery datepicker inside the directive). Plaine jquery and angular doesn't blend well